# Android Switch widget textOn and textOff not working in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-switch

The behavior of the switch widget changed in Lollipop (5.0).

```
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/another_view"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/another_view"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textOff="@string/disabled"
        android:textOn="@string/enabled"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        />
```

Rendered switch when targetSdkVersion=19:

[image]

Rendered switch when targetSdkVersion=21:

[image]

Note that preview rendering in Android Studio still produces a switch with text, but the switch loses it's text when an apk built with targetSdkVersion=21 is run on a device with Lollipop (Nexus 5). Running an apk built with targetSdkVersion=19 on the same Lollipop device renders the switch properly with text as expected.

Why? Any suggested workarounds?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Text is not shown by default under Material theme since the switch widget assets don't work well with text. Any text that you do set will be used to describe the content to accessibility services.

You can change this using the [`android:showText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#attr_android:showText) property or [`Switch.setShowText(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#setShowText(boolean)) method.

```
<Switch
    ...
    android:showText="true" />
```

If you are using AppCompat switches, use `app:showText` instead.

Comment: This attribute is indeed supported from API level 21 onwards.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work any more, using 23.4.0 running on an N-Preview3 device. 
Edit: Should be `app:showText="true"`

Comment: @behelit If you are using AppCompat, then yes.

Comment: This works but not good for the `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` becauae the text then is visible awkwardly over the switch thumb.

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me. But, the labels are shrinking in Android N.

Comment: Any work around to make it look better or a way to always use the old switch?

Comment: Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.Switch style is behind that trusty old squarish look