# How can I put the state text into the switch track?

Tags: android, switch-statement, view, customization

I want to create this custom Switch:

[image]

I searched a lot and I found nothing useful about how to customize a Switch putting the thumb ball and the state text inside of the track.

====== Solved:

I used the library https://github.com/kyleduo/SwitchButton, and thats great!

Comment: Have you seen this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415907/switchpreferencecompat-androidswitchtextoff-switchtexton-doesnt-work) ?

Comment: You can try this library https://github.com/kyleduo/SwitchButton

Comment: @Vucko, I don't want to show just the switch state text... I want to show it in the "track" instead the "thumb"...

Comment: @SanifSS Nice library, I will try to use it. Thanks :)